# Adding files with external link to Documents & Media

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, documents, document-storage

I'm trying to add an external link to a file and this external link should be stored in the same way as a file is stored inside of Liferay's Documents and Media portlet instead of uploading a file.

We have a collection of both PDFs and web forms (externally to liferay) and I want them all to be browsable and searchable from the same location within the Documents and Media portlet.

Does anyone know any kind of hack to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Forget the document library portlet for your special case. It's not possible to store link to external file nor asset.

To me the best choice is a custom Web content structure and template. Build a structure that can store external reference and description and any other info you need. 
Associate a template to the structure to have a display form. 
Use an asset publisher to view data in page. Using this way the content will be searchable and browseable.

@baxtheman